# Ajax call causing XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

#### AJAX Error:

> ***XMLHttpRequest:*** Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2

#### Js Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '\ImportData\DataFileUpload',
    data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function () { lpImport.Show(); },
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
        ImportSuccessMessage.SetVisible(true);
        ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
        lpImport.Hide();
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(errorThrown);
        ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
    }
});
```

#### Results:

The Debugger yields:

- *`errorThrown`* is `""`
- *`textStatus`* is `"error"`.

#### Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

#### My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DataFileUpload(string positionDate)
{
    // Reset validation error collection
    ImportDataValidationErrors = new List<ImportFileRecord>();
    string[] errs;
    try
    {
        Dictionary<string, double> retDictAPI = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        DateTime dateValue;
        DateTime.TryParse(positionDate, out dateValue);
        var HoldAPI = "SomeAPI";
        retDictAPI = ProcessImportFileAPI(HoldAPI);
        string ReturnVal = "Import is successful";
        return Content(ReturnVal);
        
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like you are timing out....

Comment: sigh. ok. I see timeout option in the Jquery - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ I will try to use it and see it helps.

Comment: is that Ajax jquery timeout or Browser timeout?

Comment: Not sure what that is going to do. Issue is with the server/network.